# Scroll UIImageView image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I want to scroll the image that is inside my UIImageView in case my finger is inside the UIImageView area and i'm moving my finger. I'm trying to do that using objective c. I got it moving, but it act weird and dont work right. Can you please show me how to do that please???

This is what i'm doing:

```
- (void)touchesMoved :(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];

        for (id sublayer in view_shape.sublayers) {


            if (sublayer ==imageView.layer) {


                if (CGRectContainsPoint(imageView.frame, touchLocation)) {


                    imageView.layer.contentsRect = CGRectMake( touchLocation.x/1000,
                                                             touchLocation.y/1000,

                                                              imageView.layer.contentsRect.size.width,

                                                              imageView.layer.contentsRect.size.height);

                }



                }

                }

            }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a scrollView and just add the imageView to it

Comment: I want to avoid that, because i want to see if that possible with imageView

Comment: why i do that is becouse if i have some object above the scroll i cant click them

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with just an instance of UIImageView. An image view will just hold on to an image and draw that.

Either add that inside a scrollview if you want a simple scroll/paging interface.

(or)

Add that to a UIView, and declare a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the UIView, and check the actions you get. Based on the `translation`, you can set the frame for the UIImageView.

Comment: I ended using scrollview, but doing:   [scroll addSubview:imageView]; make me able to scroll, but doing: [scroll.layer addSublayer:imageView.layer]; does not ??? why i need the second one to work